# How do you say "please sit down and stop moving"?

Tags: traduction, impératif

I want to know how to say:

> You should sit down and please stop moving.

Comment: Since the person is standing, I doubt if the moving you wish to stop involves "fidgeting" but if it does (or for future reference when it does), you could consider adding some figurative playfulness with:   "... et [arrête/z de gigoter/bouger comme un/des asticot/s!"](https://www.french-word-a-day.com/2005/06/asticoter.html)

Answer (score 5):

*Assieds-toi* (sit down) *et ne bouge plus* (and stop moving)

Comment: En tant que parent j'utilise plutôt le terme **reste tranquille** au lieu de **ne bouge plus**

Comment: @hoplageiss j'en doute pas, mais elle demandait la traduction, donc autant donner la plus proche ! Pour ma part c'est "TU TE CALMES ET TU TE TAIS" :)

Answer (score 2):

Assieds-toi et arrête de bouger !

Answer (score 1):

I just remembered this particular kind of imperative (actually 'mode indicatif') that is sometimes used with children and pets. It conveys a stronger command than just the imperative mood. Point with finger for greater effect.

> Tu t'asseois et tu arrêtes de bouger.

This is somewhat analogous to english '**You** don't talk back to me' used as imperative.

Answer (score 0):

To a child :

" Assieds-toi et tiens-toi tranquille"

"Assieds toi et cesse de remuer dans tous les sens"

---

To a dog : "assis, pas bouger"